# Remote filesystems in POSIX conformant systems

Tags: shell, filesystems, posix

Is it possible to determine which filesystems are mounted localy or remotely in `POSIX` conformant system from `shell`? I can't find any commands, all `df -l` and `find -local` aren't specified in standard (in spite of their presence *de facto* on `linux`, `Solaris`, `HP-UX` (but not on `AIX`)).

Answer (score 0):

Try the "mount" command...this will display all the mount points: local and remote.

Comment: The `mount` command is not mentioned in the POSIX specification. You should at least describe how `mount` can be used to distinguish between local and remote filesystems.